# "likely to" vs "likely"

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, adverbs

This sentence is from a TOEFL material:

> According to the news report, this investment by the company will *likely* provide a major boost to the economy because it will lead to the development of new technologies for export.

I usually put preposition **to** after the adverb **likely**, but here in this sentence, the word clearly hasn't been used that way.

Now I'm confused about when to put preposition **to** after the adverb **likely**.

Will this sentence still be grammatical if I put preposition **to** after the adverb **likely**? If so, why then is the preposition **to** omitted in this sentence?

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for your advice:) then "will likely" is special exception in the grammar? Also, reference to your advice, can I change the sentence like -> ~company will be likely to provide a major boost~?

Comment: @JasonBassford wow thankyou! I have never known that "likely" can function as adverb(I should see carefully when I look up grammar section in Cambridge..)

Comment: I realized I'd said enough in comments to turn them into an actual answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although **was likely to** and **is likely to** are normal, the specific construction of **will likely to** is ungrammatical—which is why it's not used in the TOEFL example.

You *can* use **to** with the construction **will be likely to**, but while it's *understandable*, it's not as common and there's no reason for the extra words.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-adverbs/likely-and-unlikely) discusses the use of **likely**, as well as other instances where it is not followed by **to**, and specifically refers to **will likely**:

> In American English, and more and more in British English, *likely* is used as a mid-position adverb (like *probably* in British English), most commonly between will and a main verb:
>
> *The new regulations* ***will likely*** *result in many people losing their jobs.*