# Can "the gender" refers to all people of one sex?

Tags: word-usage

> Netball was what females most likely chose to play here despite its unpopularity **among the opposite gender**.

**Does "the opposite gender" correctly refer to males in general here?**

By the way, I don't want to post another question just for this, so if you don't mind, should there be a comma before "despite"? This is not the main question, though.

Comment: Yes. a comma would be useful and yes, _opposite gender_ means _males_ here. But the sentence is rather awkward and a little coy. I would say, _Most women here chose to play netball, despite its unpopularity among men_. You could move 'here' to just before the comma if the location is important.

Comment: Thank you! A little context to explain why I wanted to avoid using "men" here. The whole sentence is: __"Soccer was the most common sport among males, while netball was what females most likely chose to play despite its unpopularity among the opposite gender."__ Since I've already used "males" earlier in the sentence, I find writing "males" again a bit repetitive. As for "men", does using "males" then "females" but then switching to "men" make your writing look inconsistent?

Comment: Could you please make some comments on both the repetition part and the switching-to-another-noun part?

Comment: Your question's title quotes the two-word phrase "the gender". However, as your question's text clarifies, the important phrase is "the opposite gender". The phrase "the gender" is strange, but the phrase "the opposite gender" is idiomatic. And you don't mean people of one sex, you mean people of one gender.

Comment: @Ken Adams: There are several problems here. People would probably know what you meant by "Soccer was the most common sport among males", but it might be better written as: _"The men preferred playing soccer: the women, netball - despite the men's aversion to it."_ You ask about how your writing looks. Perhaps you should think more about how it _sounds_. Also, it's a common mistake, but _likely_ means _probable_: not _probably_. So "what females most _probable_ chose to play" is wrong.

Comment: But according to the dictionary, likely is also an adverb, could you have a look at the examples in this [link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/likely_2)?

Comment: Yes. It can also be an adverb. Please read [THIS](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/likely). Also, [this question and its answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168510/likely-to-vs-likely) may be helpful.

Comment: I've read the answer and I'm still confused about how "most likely chose", as in my sentence, is incorrect, but the sentence "We will most likely see him later" or "The new regulations will likely result in many people losing their jobs" is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is "awkward".  It seems like you are avoiding saying the word "men".  There are some words that are taboo in English, and we might use expressions of various complexity to avoid insulting people, and that's what it looks like you are doing if you use "the opposite gender".

From a strictly technical point of view it is also incorrect. "Gender" is a property of nouns in certain languages (such as Latin, French or German).  It is sometimes by extension used to talk about people, but some consider that to be a misuse of the word.  People have *sex*, not *gender*.

So keep it simple.  Women (not females) chose to play netball, but it was unpopular with men.  The comma helps but probably isn't required.

Comment: It amuses (and mildly annoys) me that the church I go to is constantly tweaking the words of familiar hymns so as to avoid the word _men_ - I call it " the M-word". (I'm all in favour of inclusive language in new texts, but do they _have_ to alter well-known old ones?)

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between women and females in writing by the way?

Comment: "Female" can be used of animals too.  "Female" can be used as an adjective, but "woman" means "adult female person", so if you are talking specifically about people, it is usually better to use "men" and "women" rather than "males" and "females".  But it is a minor point, which doesn't affect understanding. The problem with "woman" is that it means "adult female person" and so can exclude female children.

Comment: Could I please ask you a private question about how the forum works in chat? I've created a chat room to invite you to but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: No need for it to be private.  If it is a question about how the forum works, the best thing to do would be to ask it in [meta.ell.se] That way it can help others.